# SQL query number of orders

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

I have two tables, `customers` and `orders`, and I want to get the number of orders made by each customer.

I tried

```
SELECT orders.order_id, customers.customer_id, 
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id  = customers.customer_id
```

but I can't count number of orders

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing aggregation:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, count(*) no_orders
FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

If you also want customers that have no order, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead, or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders o WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id) no_orders
FROM customers c
```